# Preventing the y-axis label being chopped off by r maps()

Tags: r, graphics, maps

Here is me making a map of the North Atlantic using the maps package, and I am losing my latitude label for the y-axis. The solution would appear to be to extend the margins to the left, but adjusting the par(mar()) argument appears to have no effect on the output: whatever number I enter into mar(), the margins remain unchanged. I have tried applying numerous pieces of advice from other posts, such as positioning the par() function after the graphics device, but to no avail, and no previous posts address the issue in r maps specifically.

```
    library(maps) # tool for maps
    library(mapdata) # all your basemaps are here

    Sample.Lat.lim=c(32,78.5)
    Sample.Long.lim=c(-77,43.5)

    png(filename = "NorthAtlantic.png", 
    width = 2400, height = 2400, res = 300, bg="white")

    par(mar = c(5,8,4,2)+0.1)

    map("worldHires", 
    xlim=Sample.Long.lim, ylim=Sample.Lat.lim, 
    col="grey", bg = "white" , 
    fill=TRUE, resolution=0)

    map.axes()
    map.scale(ratio = FALSE)

    title(main = "Map of the North Atlantic", xlab = "Longitude", ylab = 
    "Latitude")

    dev.off()
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem.  I run your code and the y axis labels look fine.

Comment: That's very odd. I have just run it on another computer and get the same flawed output. Can you suggest why that might be?

Comment: UPDATE: This only appears to be a problem with the output device, eg png() pdf() etc. When I run the code without the device and view using the R or R-Studio console, the output is as desired in terms of seeing the labels, although the relative sizes of all the text becomes skewed, so this is not ideal. Can anyone suggest a way to communicate my desires for the margins to the png graphics device?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't reproduce your problem (even with png() my output looks fine), map() has a few peculiar ways in dealing with the graphics. I have noticed differences e.g. when using Rstudio or running R from the command line on Linux.

map() actually takes "mar" as an argument and adapts margins (and aspect ratio, ...) before plotting a map, with default value  `mar = c(4.1, 4.1, par("mar")[3], 0.1)`, so the way to adapt margins would be to pass them as an argument in the map() call:

```
map("worldHires", mar=c(5,8,4,2)+0.1 , ...)
```

As an aside, I just want to warn you that "worldHires" is a *very* outdated world map (it has USSR, Yugoslavia...). If "world" really is not good enough four your purpose, and you want a newer map, you might want to install the package rnaturalearth. Then you can do

```
map(ne_countries(10), mar=c(5,8,4,2)+0.1 , ...)
```

wheras the standard "world" corresponds to ne_countries(50).